# Sending an email in Java with commons-mail

Tags: java, email, ssl

So I'm trying to send a code to my email with Java. I started out with javax.mail but remember I had problems with it last time I used it so I moved on to Apache Commons Mail.

I'm getting a bunch of errors though. On SSL, I'm getting a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` and on TLS, I'm getting a handful of errors:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2000)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

When I did a quick Google search, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore). Now because I'm a complete idiot, I do not understand the answer.

What can I do to resolve the errors? Whether it be preventing the Timeout on SSL or the others on TLS.

**EDIT:** I do not have a problem sending emails and `MessageException` is NOT my problem so please stop answering with that.

Comment: Post your code! What mail provider are you using to send your mail?

Comment: @kevcodez I'm using GMail. I don't think that part is actually relevant though.

Answer (score 4):

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
...

// add this line
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

...
email.send();
```

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember that had a similar issue with sending emails too.

I'll show on example of `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl`. Basically there are several approaches for handling this case. The answer that you've found will also work but it will work on the JVM level.
I've stopped not on the JVM approach like you've found.

#### What should be done

Add host (for example let's take a look at gmail host: `smtp.gmail.com`). By adding host to the trusted - everything started to work as expected. In my case I had to add this host to the

`Part of spring xml configuration`

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${mail.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mail.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mail.password}"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">${mail.transport.protocol}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">${mail.smtp.ssl.trust}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`Properties file`

```
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=587
mail.username=user@gmail.com
mail.password=password
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
```

*Take into account that you should give the appropriate **permissions** in case of **gmail** from the **security console**.*

#### UPDATE

Did you have a chance to try the code below from the official website of [Apache Common Email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html):

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

Comment: That's the exact code I use (in regards to Commons-Email). Doesn't sort anything though.

Comment: Have you done this: Take into account that you should give the appropriate permissions in case of gmail from the security console.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that but I have used a correct username and password.

Comment: Also go to this link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and enable access to your account. It should solve your issue.

Comment: I have 2-step verification enabled on my account so I have a app password for this.

Comment: Create a new account and give it a try without 2-factor verification. If the steps below won't help then we'll try other approaches :)

Answer (score 0):

Using library javax.mail with version 1.5.0-b01
you can find that there is simple method to avoid that kind of errors. Here is example that i used sometime ago and it works pretty much fine:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);
        props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", socketFactory);
```

If you are using maven you can add this dependency:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same kind of error, here is the solution for it

add this line: props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

Reference: http://javainfinite.com/java/send-email-using-gmail-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

to resolve the ssl hank shake issue persisted in java 6.get certificateds from java 7.java 7 have the certificates file having the capability of ignoring certificate authentication.

copy the "cacerts" file from following java 7 directory

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security

and paste it in

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\security

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

is that the certificate chain is broken. That means that the provider might be using a self signed certificate which is not trusted by the client system.
The trusted Certificates are stored in the cacerts in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\security as described in an answer above.

A solution to this might be to add the Root certificates or intermediate certificates that are missing to cacerts. Of course you do that if you trust the host that provides these certificates. i.e. usually corporations tent to create their own certificates for internal use.